# android fragmentActivity can be on intent?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

im new with fragments (atm i hate it, was rly easy with tabs :P) and i am using support package for fragments in api8 and when i call a fragment with a intent i get an error saying that class can not be found.

so i dont know if this is the right way to do it.

My app starts with an activity that loads some data from a web services, after that i want to go fragmentsTabspager.java (the one from the example of google)

If i create a intent and call method startActivity(Intent) i get the error.

the manifest is correct and the classes are in different package.

help pls!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying start activity inside a fragment try using

```
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: and from an activity? how do i call a fragmentActivity?

Comment: I didnt get your question. getActivity will return the activity that the fragment belongs too.

Comment: Question is, how to call a FragementActivity from a Activity using Intent ?